# com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Hello': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array,)

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, multipartform-data, jackson-databind

I am having problem sending React multipart form data to backend MySQL using Java.
When I test for React and Java individually in Postman, it works fine. The problem occurs when I use the form to send the user data along with a picture from frontend to backend, I get Unrecognized token error. I have researched this error a lot and can't seem to find the solution.  Please help where I am going wrong.

React:

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState()
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState()
const [email, setEmail] = useState()
const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState()
const [file, setFile] = useState()

const send = event => {
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append("user", firstName)
    data.append("file", file)


    Axios.post("/new/sale", data).then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

}
```

Controller

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/sale")
    public ResponseEntity<Response> createPost(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                               @RequestParam("user") String user)
            throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();
        Sale sale = obj.readValue(user, Sale.class);
        sale.setPicture(file.getBytes());
        sale.setFileName(file.getOriginalFilename());

        Sale sales = saleRepository.save(sale);
        if(sales != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Response>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<Response>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

POJO

```
 @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String phoneNumber;
private Date createdDate;
private Date updatedDate;
private byte [] picture;
private String fileName;
```

Comment: I'm genuinely curious about something: why do you include the code as screenshot? Isn't more convenient to copy the code as text? is there a particular reason?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the header of the request send by axios. You have to edit your request to set header `content-type` to `multipart/form-data`:

```
const config = {
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
     }
 }
```

And add this config like 3rd paramter to axios POST request:

```
Axios.post("/new/sale", data , config).then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```